# Java: regular expression: difference between "\\/" and "/"

Tags: java, regex, string

Is there any difference between regular expressions `x1 = "\\/"` and `x2 = "/"`?

I could not find and strings `s`, such that `s.split(x1)` would not be equal to `s.split(x2)`. (The same holds, when I replace `/` by, e.g., `a`.) I am on Windows.

Comment: You will have a difference when you use reserved characters like '.' '\', etc

Comment: try to print the content of `"\\/`, `"/"` and you might find the difference yourself

Comment: This is actually a really good question.

Comment: You ask what the difference between `\/` and `/` patterns are. None as you can see for yourself at http://regex101.com.

Comment: @KevinEsche This is precisely the reason why I am asking this question, since the first one gives `\/`, while the second one `/`. However, if I split "a\\/b", I get `[a\, b]` in both cases, which I find weird.

Comment: Reopened as the duplicate was inappropriate. The topic there are regexes in general and, even after going through that huge pile of text, I still couldn't find an explicit statement that answers this question.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Neither could I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no difference. 
`x1` is actually `\/` but `/` doesn't need backslash escaping (unlike `\`) and it's not a special string (tab, new line etc.)

```
String t = "th/is i/s a /test \\/t";
String r1 = "/";
String r2 = "\\/";
String[] t1 = t.split(r1);
for (int i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(t1[i]);
}
```

OR

```
String[] t2 = t.split(r2);
for (int i = 0; i < t2.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(t2[i]);
}
```

these two produce the same output.

Comment: i would think that `\/` ia an invalid regex? you have to escape a special char?

Comment: it's not regex. it's a simple text (*not* java text)

Comment: the original question is explicitly about the regex string

Comment: You misunderstand my response... `\/` is what the regex would look like if one didn't need to escape a special char...

Comment: @sharonbn "A backslash may be used prior to a non-alphabetic character regardless of whether that character is part of an unescaped construct."